# iOS Obj-C view with custom class init once

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I have 3 View Controllers, name it :

```
- Dashboard
- Map
- Location List
```

In the MapVC, I attach 1 big uiview with custom class of XMapView. Inside the XMapView I have this code

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)aRect {
if ((self = [super initWithFrame:aRect])) {
    [self commonInit];
}
return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder {
if ((self = [super initWithCoder:coder])) {
    [self commonInit];
}
return self;
}

- (void)commonInit{
UIView *mapView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"XMapView"
                                                 owner:self
                                               options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

mapView.frame = self.bounds;
mapView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[self addSubview: mapView];
}
```

So basically the MapVC just inject the XmapView and display it.

I have this code in my MapVC controller. Please note that I have outleted the View with custom class inside the MapVC to the .h file.

```
//.h file
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet XMapView *mapStoreView;

//.m file
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

// this following code will load the Map from the XMapView to the MapVC
[self.mapStoreView loadMap:self.results viewController:self selectedOutletFromList:self.selectedOutletFromList];
}
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
[self.mapStoreView removeFromSuperview];
self.mapStoreView = nil;
self.mapStoreView.mkMapView.delegate = nil;
[self.mapStoreView.mkMapView removeAnnotations:self.mapStoreView.mkMapView.annotations];
self.results = nil;
}
```

The sequence is Dashboard -> MapVC -> Location List

Test Case :

```
1. Dashboard -> MapVC, map will load.
2. MapVC -> Location List -> MapVC, map will not load.
3. Dashboard -> MapVC -> Dashboard -> MapVC, map will always load.
```

What is the problem here?? Am I missing something?

Comment: why you are   [self.mapStoreView removeFromSuperview];
self.mapStoreView = nil; You are making this from outlet and you are not alloc again. so it is not showing. Do not remove this

Comment: because of you are remve map in viewDidDisappear .

Comment: if it is not showing, why is it loaded when i come from Dashboard to MapVC?

Comment: because you are nil iboutlet in viewDidDisappear and when your come from home it will create new one so.

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
[self.mapStoreView removeFromSuperview];
self.mapStoreView = nil;
self.mapStoreView.mkMapView.delegate = nil;
[self.mapStoreView.mkMapView removeAnnotations:self.mapStoreView.mkMapView.annotations];
self.results = nil;
}
```

When you push to a new viewController called  Location List,you removed your mapStoreView from super view,when you back, you didn't recover the mapStoreView,So it's gone.

viewDidDisappear would be called if self is disappeard,including push a new viewcontroller,pop from navigationController , present a new viewcontroller and dismiss self controller.

If you want to free memory,you should do these job in dealloc method which would be called when the controller be dealloced.

like this:

```
        -dealloc
        {
[self.mapStoreView removeFromSuperview];
        self.mapStoreView = nil;
        self.mapStoreView.mkMapView.delegate = nil;
        [self.mapStoreView.mkMapView removeAnnotations:self.mapStoreView.mkMapView.annotations];
        self.results = nil;
    }
```

Comment: after i use your dealloc function, the memory won't decrease sir, instead it keep increasing ( memory leak )

Comment: I don't konw exactly job to free memory,This is just a example.You should remove the code in viewDidDisappear to resolve your problem,Memory leak is anothor problem,you should analyse your code,find retain cycle and resolve it , let your controller to be free.Fix memory leak is always a complex work

Answer (score 0):

Change as below :

You are make nil IBOutlet of  mapStoreView so  it will not loads while you come from location

It will load while HomeVc to MapVc because your are create new instance of mapVc so that new iboutlet created there .

**Your Test case**

```
1. Dashboard -> MapVC, map will load. - because new instance of MapVC created on  Dashboard 
2. MapVC -> Location List -> MapVC, map will not load. - because you are nil iboutlet in ViewDidDisappear so it is not longer for load.
3. Dashboard -> MapVC -> Dashboard -> MapVC, map will always load. - because new instance of MapVC created on  Dashboard always.
```

**Make changes as below**

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
   [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

**This method called automatically when your viewcontroller deallocated.**

```
 -(void)dealloc
            {
             [self.mapStoreView removeFromSuperview];
            self.mapStoreView = nil;
            self.mapStoreView.mkMapView.delegate = nil;
            [self.mapStoreView.mkMapView removeAnnotations:self.mapStoreView.mkMapView.annotations];
            self.results = nil;
        }
```

Comment: So, I have to remove the self.mapStoreView = nil in the viewWillDisappear?

Comment: yes. you need to remove all mapStoreView's related lines

Comment: why did you are removed in viewDidDisappear ?

Comment: save memory. if i did not remove from superview, the memory will keep increase whenever the user use the map

Comment: then remove in dealloc .

Comment: remove above lines and check your mapview loads while come back from location VC and let me know.

Comment: Yes the map view loaded when come back from the location VC, but the memory leaks

Comment: then create mapview programmatically instead of storyboard . then create map in ViewWillAppear and add to view .  and remove on ViewDidDisapperar